# Guice Servlet call getting 404 Not Found

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, guice

## ****UPDATE****

Just realized that I had RequestBuilder.PUT instead of RequestBuilder.GET...changing that line now gives me a 404 Not Found Error.  This is the firebug output:

```
Response Headerspretty print

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 999

Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2013 21:23:48 GMT



Request Headerspretty print

GET /a-bcd/abcd//BMDWebUtil HTTP/1.1

Host: xx.xx.xx.xx:8080

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Content-Type: application/json

Referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/a-bcd/

Cookie: JSESSIONID=29CB8485902F8B31A0E237B6689B3118

Authorization: Basic YWxsVXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==

Connection: keep-alive

Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

I'm guessing that I have some path incorrectly set...I did notice that in the firebug output next to "GET" the path has a double / in it...could that be the problem??  Where would this double / be coming from?

Thank you for any input!!

#### ****end Update****

I created a guice servlet that should be inserting a String into a webpage.  It's a very simple servlet.  I am getting a 403 Forbidden error when using RequestBuilder to call the servlet.

Here is my Firebug output:

```
Response Headersview source
Content-Length  961
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 05 Oct 2013 05:34:14 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization   Basic YWxsVXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    application/json
Cookie  JSESSIONID=29CB8485902F8B31A0E237B6689B3118
Host    10.13.36.85:8080
Referer http://10.13.36.85:8080/a-bcd/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
```

BCDWebUtilServlet Class:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    try 
        String name= webUtil.getName();

        out.print(classification);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    try 
        String name = webUtil.getName();

        out.print(name);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }    
}
```

EntryPoint class: (GWT.getModuleBaseURL() outputs: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/a-bcd/abcd/)

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // This is required for Gwt-Platform proxy's generator
    DelayedBindRegistry.bind(ginjector);        

    ginjector.getPlaceManager().revealCurrentPlace();
    setUpEnv();

}

private void setUpEnv(){
    try {
        Window.alert(GWT.getModuleBaseURL());
        RequestBuilder rb = requestBuilderProvider.get(RequestBuilder.PUT, GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/BCDWebUtil");
        rb.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if(response.getStatusCode() != 200){
                    // there was an error, add to error display
                    Window.alert("Error");
                }else{
                    classification = response.getText();
                    Window.alert("Success! " + classification);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException ex) {
    }
}
```

ServletModule class:

```
serve("/a-bcd/abcd/BCDWebUtil/*").with(BCDWebUtilServlet.class);
```

.gwt.xml:

```
<servlet path="/BCDWebUtil" class="com.abcd.server.guice.servlet.BCDWebUtilServlet"/>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: moved update above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my problem was the path...the ServletModule class should be:

```
serve("/abcd/BCDWebUtil/*").with(BCDWebUtilServlet.class);
```

Also, when creating RequestBuilder in my EntryPoint file I need a "/" at the end of the path:

```
RequestBuilder rb = requestBuilderProvider.get(RequestBuilder.PUT, GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/BCDWebUtil/");
```

I found a tip online that said to try entering different URL paths in the browser until you get a 500 Error...that is the path you need to be calling.